# vintage auto headlamp dimming

Tags: automotive, dimmer, vintage

I am restoring a 1930 Stutz, the headlamps originally used a resistor to dim the single filament bulbs from high to low beam.
The vehicle is now 12 volts, to dim the lamps the correct amount I have determined a 3 volt drop will be fine.

Question- what resistor is required to reduce the bulbs (two 48 watt).

Peter H.

Comment: Use a simple PWM motor controller module instead. These are  cheaper, smaller, easier to obtain, easier to mount and waste less power. You can even modify it in such a way to do a slow start, which saves your light bulbs.

Answer (score 1):

Total full load is 2x 48 watts = 96 watts. On 12V, this is a resistance of 1.5 ohms because power = \$V^2/R\$. With only 9V across the lamps a current of 6 amps flows hence, the dropper resistor has to drop 3V at 6 amps and this means it has a resistance of 0.5 ohms.

However, a word of caution, as the lights dim they don't run as hot and their resistance lowers so you might need a resistor that is a tad under 0.5 ohms.

The resistor's power dissipation is 18 watts (\$I^2R\$) so choose one that can easily handle this power without burning.

Answer (score 1):

The question is harder than you might expect, because the resistance of the bulbs changes depending on how hot they are (light bulbs are not ohmic).  That being said, you can get a ballpark figure by working it out *as if* the bulbs are  ohmic.  The power in a single bulb is given by:

> P = V² / R<sub>bulb</sub>

which means

> R<sub>bulb</sub> = PV²
>   R<sub>bulb</sub> = (48 watts)*(12 volts²)
>   R<sub>bulb</sub> = 3 Ω

This means that the effictive resistance of a bulb is 3 Ω while hot (running at 12 V).  Note that they will measure a lot lower resistance than this while they're cold, because the filament resistance will be a lot lower when the bulb is cold.

You want a 3:1 ratio of the voltage between the bulb and the resistor, which would mean R = R<sub>bulb</sub> / 3, so, nominally you'll need a 1 Ω resistor.  At 3 volts, you'll the power dissipation in the resistor would be (3 V)² / (1 Ω) = 9 W.  In practice you'll need a higher power rating to account for the effect of the reduced bulb-resistance when it dims, plus a safety margin.

Note: (1) I did the calculation for a single bulb, and got 1 Ω, 9 W.  I just saw someone else did it as a single resistor for both bulbs, and got 0.5 Ω, 18 W, which is consistent.

Comment: That's with engine off, Generator runs at 14.2 V which is how I got to ~2 ohms for both

Answer (score 1):

You need somewhat less than 0.5 ohms to drop the voltage of the (much cooler) filaments by 3V. The actual voltage of an automotive electrical system is more like 14V when the alternator (or perhaps generator in your case) is operational, but I'll ignore that.

Rlamp(hot) = V^2/P = 144V^2/96W =  1.5 ohms. So to drop 3V if the lamp remained the same resistance would take 3/9 of that or 0.5 ohms. Since the resistance of the bulb will drop significantly we know it will be less than 0.5 ohms. The power dissipation will certainly be less than 24W (full brightness current x 3V).

Probably overkill, but you can get a 300W 0.5 ohm adjustable resistor for about $45 from stock. Ohmite part number [E300KR50E](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/303/res_280-218102.pdf). You slide the strap back and forth on the resistor until you get the brightness you want, then tighten it down. A bit of a monster at 8.5" (215mm) long.

[image]

Given the 300W rating, it's acceptable to use only a relatively small part of the resistor, and you could also use a 0.8 ohm or E300K1R0E 1 ohm part to be sure you got the headlights dim enough. The latter is slightly cheaper at 38 USD, so a bit more attractive in every way.

Answer (score 0):

For a linear R power is \$ V^2/R=P\$ thus \$ 14V^2/96W=2\Omega \$ and \$ 9V^2/3\Omega=33W or 1/3 max\$ thus adding \$1\Omega , @9V/3\Omega=3A \$ or \$3W \$.  Unfortunately Tungsten filament R_cold= 10% R_hot when off or \$0.3 \Omega \$ thus resistor draws 144 Watts until bulbs heat up. 12*12 or if turned on after generator runs 14*14V/1~200 watts !

This is why they put the headlamps in series for old cars in low beam and parallel for high beam .

You can do thus with a DPDT 10A relay and some re-wiring with remote ground at relay instead of chassis at bulb and heavy wire.AWG12 to 14 unless relay near bulb to battery.

Or use a 40A PWM (12V/0.3R) as I might suggest, *but would not do*,  for surge currents and heat rise. Although they are cheap on Ebay/Amazon..its not period accurate

Use the series approach unless you really want 11V on each when running. It is easy to test and you will find current with engine off = 8A parallel ~6A in series at half voltage thus around 72W due to NTC effects of tungsten or 30% less power.

[These](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/266195/vintage-auto-headlamp-dimming) will run cooler with chassis mount and are cheaper. 1 per pair of headlamps [image]

Buy two , 0.5 and 1 Ohm and choose the best effect.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/vishay-huntington-electric-inc/FSOT2011ER5000KE/FSOT20-.5-ND/953827

WoW! I am amazed by the depth of this.

Originaly there was a very crude ceramic resistor bolted to the chassis rail.

Your thoughts on the attached product please.

Comment: 0.5 Ohm will drop much less than 1 Ohm as per your spec, but may do the trick to avoid flashing headlights or not.    *Turning off Engine drops 2 V this would be ~1.5V instead of 3V drop*  You can buy extra and use 1 or 2 for each lamp

Comment: but at that price a used automotive relay is free plus wiring.   ceramic R is designed to run very hot. If you have leather seats use nichrome wire and heat the seats with it. lol